# Match + offset in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Probably quite simple, but cannot get it together.

[image]

I simply want to match cell B2 with the range D2:D12. If there is an exact match, then pull the link next to the table with destinations, and give that value in A1.

Thanks so much for the help!

// Non-coder building chatbot backend in Google Sheets :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try A1:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,D1:E15,2,0)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was looking into that formula, but did not get it to work. I need to get better at this :)